# Adding a value to a datetime column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting this error:

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

```
CASE U.BasePool 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) > U.BasePool THEN 'IN-OVERAGE'
                    --WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) + (SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum) > U.BasePool THEN DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE())
                    ELSE  CASE WHEN MonthNum<1 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(MM,CAST(ROUND((U.BasePool - SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)) 
                                /(SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum),0) as Int), GETDATE()),101)

                    --(basepool - sumcontract) / (sumcontract/monthNum ) is the expected months to reach overage
                END 
            END
            END AS  ExpectedDate
```

Comment: Could you please give use what the table structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max `datetime` value is '9999-12-31', so you can add around 95840 months to `getdate()`
This produces your error exactly:

```
select dateadd(month,95841, getdate() )
```

You must've made mistake in calculating number of months to add.

Comment: Yes, i have tried it. you are correct.can you please suggest or help me in this. i have edited the query.

Comment: I don't know your data structure, and you didn't explain what you're doing, exactly...